# How to use Gettext for mail templates

Tags: php, localization, internationalization, gettext

I am working on a PHP project that now switched to using Gettext-based language files for localization stuff. Before that, we simply used files with PHP dicts (arrays) instead.

Until now we had template files for every email we sent out, with a few {variables} being replaced in there.

Does Gettext offer anything similar? Or how are mail templates usually assembled?
(Obviously, templates are more flexible regarding order of elements than concatenating different strings is.)

Comment: gettext is not a template engine.